# qfKey are always invalid when returning from payment processor in contribution

Tags: civicontribute

I have a site which has been running for some time.  Recently whenever anyone makes a contribution (via PayPal).  When they click return to merchant they get the following error:

[image: Error]

This is caused by the qfKey coming back in the URL being invalid.  The error starts on line 308 of civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php and is caused by CRM_Core_Key::validate($key, $name, $addSequence) returning null.

I have disabling all my custom templates and the issue persists.  Looking at the code it should get the qfKey from the request, so what is causing it to be invalid?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? Are you creating any user while submitting the contribution?

Comment: Cookies are enabled, I can see a PHPSESSID being set.  Yes a user is being created when the submission is taking place.

Comment: You have an interesting point disabling the account creation is enough to fix the problem.  Although not ideal

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you have

1. Browser cookies disabled
2. CiviCRM cache cleared when users is on payment processor gateway and doing payment.
3. User is created at the time of submitting contribution and causes session to clear.

Comment: Yes it appears that number 3 is my issue, is there any way to fix this though?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, but it involves existing users not created users. See [my question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39156/payments-fail-with-paypal-standard-and-could-not-find-a-valid-session-key) for a description and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Description:

The issue is related to the getReturnSuccessUrl() function in the Payment.php file of CiviCRM. The original code is causing a problem where the query parameter _qf_ThankYou_display is not properly appended to the $qfKey. As a result, the success URL is not being generated correctly.

Solution:
To fix this issue, we need to modify the getReturnSuccessUrl() function by appending the _qf_ThankYou_display=1 parameter to the $qfKey. This will ensure that the success URL is generated with the correct parameters.

Original Code:

protected function getReturnSuccessUrl($qfKey) {
if (isset($this->successUrl)) {
return $this->successUrl;
}

return CRM_Utils_System::url($this->getBaseReturnUrl(), [
'_qf_ThankYou_display' => 1,
'qfKey' => $qfKey,
],
TRUE, NULL, FALSE
);
}

Updated Code:

protected function getReturnSuccessUrl($qfKey) {
if (isset($this->successUrl)) {
return $this->successUrl;
}

// Append the '_qf_ThankYou_display=1' parameter to the $qfKey.
$qfKey .= '&_qf_ThankYou_display=1';

return CRM_Utils_System::url($this->getBaseReturnUrl(), [
'qfKey' => $qfKey,
],
TRUE, NULL, FALSE
);
}

With this modification, the success URL will be generated correctly, and the issue should be resolved. Remember to apply the change in the Payment.php file as described in the solution above.